# Keep Android Fragment/Activity from reloading on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

Perhaps I don't get the principle of Fragments; but I would like everything to stay the same if I switch to landscape or portrait.  I have an AsynTask that populates a listview and displays a progress dialog.

If I switch orientation of the device, the "Loading..." dialog comes back on (and a lot of time the app crashes) - this shows me the AsynTask is being called again.  How do I just change the orientation without dropping and reloading the view?

For what it's worth, I call the AsynTask in the ListFragment onActivityCreated.

Also the crash's from LogCat report this:

```
07-29 07:41:02.596: E/AndroidRuntime(15338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 07:41:02.596: E/AndroidRuntime(15338): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This is odd.

I had a "finish()" in my "onStop".  I removed that and all worked well.

I also took out the getListView from my AsynTask and move into the onActivityCreate